# SQLite-Net: use comparison in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-order-by, sqlite-net

I'm using a SQLite-Net database and would like to order by a comparison, like this:

```
var value1 = 10;

var items = connection.Table<Item>.OrderBy(i => i.Field1 > value1).ToArray();
```

(*Note: value1 and Field1 are both integers*)

This throws an exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Order By does not support: i => i.Field1 > value1

As a workaround, I've now split this query into two parts:

1. Select the item where Field1 is larger than value1
2. Select the item where Field1 is smaller than or equal to value1

And then these results are combined to a single result.

**Is there a better way to handle this using SQLite-Net?**

Comment: And what is the important part of the error message?

Comment: My bad, left the last part out, because it was exactly stating the ORDER BY clause. Added that part now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach was:

```
var value1 = 10;
var items = new List<Item>();
items.AddRange(connection.Table<Item>.Where(i => i.Field1 <= value1));
items.AddRange(connection.Table<Item>.Where(i => i.Field1 > value1));
```

But I finally settled for a single query:

```
var value1 = 10;
var items = connection
              .Query<Item>(@"SELECT * 
                             FROM [Item] 
                             ORDER BY [Field1] > ? ASC", value1);
```